# custom alert dialog not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display a custom alert dialog whose structure has been defined in an XML file. This is the code I used.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(findViewById(R.layout.inputform));
builder.show();
```

It is fired when a button is clicked. However, the window was not getting displayed. I got this transparent grey layer on top of the screen and could not click on anything. Some basic codes like using `setMessage` or displaying checkboxes work well, though. Can anyone point out where I do wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Room name" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:hint="Enter room name" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Point id" android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:hint="Enter point id" android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow03" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="OK" android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `findViewById` is for finding a specific view in the current activity´s layout, not for loading a whole layout.

You can use [@Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828329/custom-alert-dialog-not-getting-displayed/4828419#4828419) answer or maybe you can inflate the layout with a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) like this:

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.inputform);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(v);
builder.show();
```

(Not tried it but I think it should work).

Comment: I've tried it before and it didn't work. Just now realized I made mistake in supplying the parentView. Thanks! Accepting this as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.inputform);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: It works! But I'm pending accepting your answer as I want to try maid450's solution. Btw, what's the difference between using Dialog and AlertDialog? Does being superclass make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding builder.create(); before builder.show().

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I'm trying the other suggestions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following class

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {


    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        }


    public static CustomDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message) {
        return show(context, title, message, false);
    }

    public static CustomDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
    }

    public static CustomDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
        return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
    }

    public static CustomDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
            boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle(null);
        dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);


        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to represent dialog...

```
AlertDialog dialog ;

AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Your Title Here");

builder.setView(view);//view is your inflate xml layout

dialog = builder.create();

    dialog.show();


dialog.dismiss();//whenever you want to dismiss ,put this line
```

simple dialog [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050721/is-this-a-dialog-or-activity/7879921#7879921)