# Is this a dialog or activity?

Tags: android

When you long press on an email in Gmail application the dialog box is shown. I'm wondering is it just a dialog or an activity represented as dialog? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it should be a `Dialog` and when you select/click the item it may be open an `Activity` based on the type of commands. However an `Activty` can be displayed as a `Dialog` but here as the items in the dialog are related to the context of the same activty therfore it can't be a new activty here.

Answer (score 2):

Your screen shot code should look like this. Here there is no need to dismiss your dialog, when selected option it automatically dismissed.

```
AlertDialog dialog ;
Charsequence str[]={"Test1","Test2"};


AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Your Title Here");
builder.setItems(str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                //here you can use like this... str[position]

            }

        });
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```