# How to display an arraylist in AlertDialog

Tags: android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

i'm trying to get an arraylist on alert dialog but i can see the list items only if i click them. any idea whats wrong with the below code .any suggestions pls....

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS); 

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 final ArrayAdapter<String> aa1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, matches);
       builder.setSingleChoiceItems(aa1, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                numbers.add(aa1.getItem(item));
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
 alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=922) when using the default themes and `AlertDialog.Builder`.

You should be able to work around it by copying the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` layout xml out of the platform and creating a local layout file with the `android:textColor` properties overridden to something other than themed text color attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this one

android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Comment: i particularly want to use this..."android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice"

Answer (score 0):

simple dialog here [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050721/is-this-a-dialog-or-activity/7879921#7879921). Just you have to pass string or charsequence array to it shows simple dialog..