# android how to customize a dialog to looks like below image

Tags: android

[image: I want this in my app]

I unable to get , Is this a activity or a customized dialog(If it is a dialog then which dialog it is?  Dialog, or AlertDialog, or AlertDialog.Builder)
Plz anybody give some idea what is used here.

Thank you

Comment: Check this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828329/custom-alert-dialog-not-getting-displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a custom dialog to me as you can see the background activity behind. You can create this custom `Dialog` by making custom layout and call `setContentView()` for the layout. Making the custom layout for dialog is similar to layout for activities.

For that particular case you gave, I might create a layout with a centered `TextView` on top  following by a divider, then continues with other `ImageView` and `TextView`. It might not look the same but somehow

Comment: If it is a dialog then for title they have .setTitle() & title come top left corner not like that. then how they customize the title to look like this?

Comment: You can create a `Dialog` without `Title` using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`. The title you saw can be a `TextView` in the content of the `Dialog`

Comment: and for the Button? What they used for button to make separate background?

Comment: that looks like `AlertDialog`'s default button, however you can still archive that with custom `Dialog`. Center `Button` inside a `LinearLayout` then set the background of the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

It is custom dialog box you only need to make custom_dialog.xml in layout folder.
And call it from your activity.
for example:
            Builder builder = new Builder(DialogActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                ----------------
}
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

```
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```